# How to write Taylor's expansion for $g(x)=0$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, jacobian

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function, and $x_*$ be a solution of the equation $g(x)=0$.

Suppose $\|J_g(x_*)\| > 0$ where $J_g(x_*)$ is the Jacobian at $x_*$. Show that there exist a positive constant $\epsilon$ such that

$$
\|g(x)\| \leq 6 \|J_g(x_*)\|\|x-x_*\|
$$

for all $x$ with $\|x-x_*\| < \epsilon$.

The prove must follow Taylor's expansion but the expansion, as far as I know, is

$$
g(x) = g(x_*) + J_g(x_*)(x-x_*) + o(\|x-x_*\|)
$$

Since $g(x_*)$ is zero, we have

$$
g(x)=  J_g(x_*)(x-x_*) + o(\|x-x_*\|)
$$

How can we come up with coefficient $6$?